# How to assign "null" or "undefined" for a property with children , in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, subdocument

I want to make the "address" property "null" or "undefined" if I haven't initialized it in mongoose. I have tried to initialize it to a null value but didn't work.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, default: null },
    address: {
      number: { type: String, default: null },
      route: { type: String, default: null },
      areaInner: { type: String, default: null },
      areaOuter: { type: String, default: null },
      country: { type: String, default: null }
    }
},{timestamps:true});

var User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);

var newUser = User({
        name: name,
        address:null
});

newUser.save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define an other schema for "address":

```
var addressSchema = new Schema({
  number: {type: String, default: null},
  ...
}); 

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, default: null},
  address: {type: addressSchema, default: null}
});
```

Comment: What will happen when I'm retrieving values? Should I write two retrieves , one for userSchema and one for addressSchema?

Comment: No if you include `address` this way the `address` object will just be a member of `user` (like in your example).